# Locationsensor does not turn off

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using a locationsensor that is active on formcreate and a Mapview with Compass and MyLocation ControlOptions turned on on design time. I want to turn the location off when the app goes to background. I use this code:

```
function Frm.OnApplicationEvent(AAppEvent:TApplicationEvent;AContext:TObject):Boolean;
var
StartupIntent: JIntent;
  begin    
    case AAppEvent of
      TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground:
      //TApplicationEvent.willbecomeinactive:
       begin
        MapView1.ControlOptions := MapView1.ControlOptions - [TMapControlOption.MyLocation];
        MapView1.ControlOptions := MapView1.ControlOptions - [TMapControlOption.Compass];
        locationsensor1.Active:=false;
        mapview1.Enabled:=false;
       end;
      TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground:
       begin
        mapview1.Enabled:=true;
        MapView1.ControlOptions := MapView1.ControlOptions + [TMapControlOption.MyLocation];
        MapView1.ControlOptions := MapView1.ControlOptions + [TMapControlOption.Compass];
        locationsensor1.Active:=true;
       end;
    end;
    Result := False;
  end;
```

but the location icon on android does not disappear. It only disappear if I kill the app.

Any idea of the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The sensor is disabled by the [ASensorEventQueue_disableSensor](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#ga03852b813887ec236a34c4aef0df4b68) function. Is there any chance that the icon sustains when the sensor is just disabled? I have a small experience with Android development, but maybe you need to temporarily destroy the `TLocationSensor` instance to make that icon disappear..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the MapView. If I put the visibility of the container of the mapview (a panel) to false, then locationsensor goes to disabled when going to background.